# Align TextView above SeekBar Thumb for RTL

Tags: java, android, textview, android-seekbar

I created an app that should be both in Hebrew and in English.

I use there `SeekBar` to let the users choose the radius of the search.

Since I have a "floating" `TextView`, I control its position relative to the position of the `SeekBar`.

For example, in the English language all work well as follows:

[image]

When the localization is changed to support rtl:

[image]

The code im using to position the TextView is:

```
int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
tv_SbDistanceText.setText( getString( R.string.ActivityLocation_Ppl_Distance, Integer.toString( progress ) ) );

float currentPosition = (float) seekBar.getWidth() / seekBar.getMax();
currentPosition = currentPosition * progress + 40;

tv_SbDistanceText.setX( currentPosition );

if (progress < 50) {
    tv_SbDistanceText.setX( currentPosition + 15 );
} else {
    tv_SbDistanceText.setX( currentPosition - 15 );
}
```

I can't figure out why it won't start from the right position.

Thank you